# How to apply gradient blur to one side of an image?

Tags: css

The goal is to blur the right side of the image like this with css only
The example:

[image]

so as you can see they applied a blurry side on top of the image. i tried the backdrop filter but didn't work, also i didn't know how to work with the mask and the clip path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to get a fairly similar result with CSS.
More detailed: [codepen](https://codepen.io/iamvdo/pen/npPdXy)

```css
.effet {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.effet img {
  position: absolute;
}
.filtre--r {
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-radial-gradient(
    center,
    closest-side,
    transparent 30%,
    black 80%
  );
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(
    closest-side at center,
    transparent 50%,
    black 110%
  );
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  mask: url("#mask-radial");
  filter: url("#filtre1");
}
.filtre:hover {
  -webkit-mask: none;
  -webkit-filter: none;
  mask: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="effet">
  <img src="http://css3create.com/squelettes/images/articles/flou-localise-1.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="filtre filtre--r" src="http://css3create.com/squelettes/images/articles/flou-localise-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<svg height="0">
  <filter id="filtre1">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```